# Want to install Centos on Virtualbox of Ubuntu platform

Tags: virtualization

As I'm using ubuntu 19.04 I'm looking to install centos on Oracle VirtualBox. but unfortunately, mouse integration is not working. someone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Then the problem arises from virtualbox side, have you try reinstall VirtualBox ?

Comment: I re-installed Virtualbox too but the problem still continues. it was throwing an error,   video mode activated cannot use a mouse integration

Comment: What error may I ask, please post them here.

Comment: video mode activated cannot use a mouse integration...

Comment: error was: the virtualmachine reports that the guest os does not support mouse pointer integration in

Comment: Isn't CentOS a server, no GUI, version? It won't use the mouse anyway so that's normal?!?